# neo4j cypher (optional relationships on null endpoints)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have simplified my complex cypher down its core issue.

```
START focus=node(2), user=node(20) 
MATCH focus-[:USER_FEED_LIST*1..15]->pointer-[:POINTER]->item,
item-[l?:NOTICE_LINK]->link<-[lu?:POST_UPVOTE]-user
RETURN link, ID(item) as item_id, item, l, lu
```

Basically what I am trying to achieve is as follows:

1. return each item in the linked list
2. for each item, return `l` and `link` if they exist, or null if not
3. if `link` is not null, return `lu` and `user` if they exist, or null if not

The problem I am having is with `3.` as the third line of the query is really saying *return any link that satisfies either of the given relationships*.

So for example, if my linked list chained 10 items, I need the query to always return 10 rows (null for `l`, `link` and `lu` if they don't exist).

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want to go with path expressions and not optional relationships?
Those path expressions return a collection of paths. You can use extract / filter to extract certain parts of those.

```
START focus=node(2), user=node(20) 
MATCH focus-[:USER_FEED_LIST*1..15]->pointer-[:POINTER]->item,
RETURN ID(item) as item_id, item, (item-[:NOTICE_LINK]->link<-[:POST_UPVOTE]-user)
```

Comment: Apologies for the hand holding, but if I try the cypher above I get *Developer: Andres claims that: This execution plan should not exist.* I should have mentioned above that I am using 2.0-M03.

Comment: Ok, I upgraded to M04, and the error is now gone. However, now the above query returns *Unknown identifier item, link, user.* Any ideas?